# Создать DataFrame из csv файлов с разной кодировкой, указанной в первой строке файла

Tags: python, pandas

Есть [1000](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12_CWlTUoM9ucrh_QvTjIfKlkB3u8INqz/view?usp=sharing) csv файлов. Они все с разными кодировками. Хочу сделать из них один DataFrame, но получаю ошибку

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 37: invalid start byte
```

csv файл устроен таким образом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть в первой строке указана кодировка, но непонятно как её передать pandas что бы он корректно считывал данные.

Пробовал так, но не работает

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

data_dir = Path("data/")
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in data_dir.glob("*.csv")])
print(df)
```

На выходе нужно получить файл csv со столбцами entity, value, string. Эти данные надо брать из этих 1000 файлов(разделитель запятая).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто делайте не однострочником, а старым добрым циклом for. В цикле считываете первую строку файла, потом передаете ее как кодировку в `read_csv`. Все собирайте в список. После цикла уже делайте `pd.concat`.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

data_dir = Path("data/")

result = []

for f in data_dir.glob("*.csv"):
    print("File:", f)
    with open(f, "rb") as file:
        # В перовой строке файла убираем пробельные символы,
        # берем текст после символа "="
        encoding = file.readline().decode().strip().partition("=")[2]  
    print("Encoding:", encoding)

    # skiprows=1 - пропускаем первую строку файла, она не должна попадать в данные
    # encoding_errors="replace" - при ошибках кодировки (не удалось декодировать указанной кодировкой) заменять символы на "?"
    # header=None - указываем, что в файле нет строки с заголовками колонок
    # on_bad_lines="warn" - выводим предупреждение, например, если в какой-то строке 4 колонки вместо 3 (а не падаем с исключением)
    result.append(pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=1, encoding=encoding, on_bad_lines="warn", encoding_errors="replace", header=None))

df = pd.concat(result)
print(df)
```

Upd.:
Полная строка для чтения csv такая:

```
result.append(pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=1, encoding=encoding, encoding_errors="replace", header=None, names=list("12345")))
```

Добавил имена колонок - 1,2,3,4,5, чтобы по умолчанию считало, что колонок 5 (в файле `test-684.csv` почему-то определяет, что в одной из строк их пять, почему - пока не понял).

Comment: Попробовал так, но ошибка ```pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 4, saw 4
```

Comment: Значит в csv проблема, написано же, что ожидалось 3 поля, найдено 4. Это уже отдельная проблема, никак с кодировкой не свяазанная.

Comment: Но во всех файлах одинаковая структура, попробовал добавить разделитель при считывании, но не помогло, добавил ссылку на файлы в вопросе.

Comment: @ЯрославСаух ну вот, значит, недостаточно одинаковая оказалась

Comment: @PavelMayorov, действительно, в некоторых файлах в третьей части одной строки есть ещё запятая

Comment: @insolor попробовал на примере нескольких файлов, код работает, но неправильно, вот вывод
https://postimg.cc/TLRGBRML

Comment: @ЯрославСаух нужно еще `header=None` передавать в read_csv. По поводу NaN - нужно смотреть конкретные файлы, которые вы грузили

Comment: @insolor с header=None всё заработало, спасибо, осталось только  сделать так что б оно все файлы воспринимало, тут уже буду думать как, ибо менять их не вариант.

Comment: @ЯрославСаух дописал итоговую строку, с которой у меня все файлы считываются

Comment: @insolor спасибо

Comment: @insolor по поводу 684 файла, там просто идёт три запятых подряд